# Removing files from the '/' folder

Tags: raspbian

I accidentally saved some files to the '/' folder, and now I can't remove them, move them, put them in a folder, or generally interact with them. I would like to get rid of them, but my computer says 'Permission Denied' and in the case of one of the files which I used `sudo rm` on it says it doesn't exist even though I can see it in the GUI. How do I solve this?

Comment: hmm, that seems to 'delete' it but the physical file in the GUI is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `sudo su` and then used the command line to go and delete everything, and it worked just fine! Hope this helps!